# What is causing my dice roller script to crash when inputting something like "10d100"

Tags: c++, dice

I have looked over my script, but i cant find out whats giving me this error. When ever I run something like "10d100", the script crashes without giving an output. Other than this, the script is working fine.

Also, "Log" is just a cout function i made with a header file.

```
int main()
{
    std::string input;
    std::string numD;
    std::string numF;
    unsigned short int numDice{};
    unsigned short int numFaces{};
    unsigned short int rollTotal{0};


    while (1)
    {
        SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 11);

        Log("Input your roll (ex. 4d6, 1d20)\n\n");

        getline(std::cin, input);

        if (input.size() == 0) {numDice = 1; numFaces = 20; break;}
        if (isdigit(input[0])) {numD.push_back(input[0]); }
        else { Log("Please use the format (XXdXX)\n\n"); return main();}


        if (isdigit(input[1])) {numD.push_back(input[1]); numDice = std::stoi(numD); }
        else if (isalpha(input[1])) { numDice = std::stoi(numD); }

        if (isdigit(input[2])) {numF.push_back(input[2]); }


        if (isdigit(input[3])) {numF.push_back(input[3]);}
        else {numFaces = std::stoi(numF); break;}

        if (isdigit(input[4])) {numF.push_back(input[4]);}
        else {numFaces = std::stoi(numF); break;}

        if (isdigit(input[5])) {numF.push_back(input[5]);}
        else {numFaces = std::stoi(numF); break;}

        break;

    }

    srand(time(NULL));

    Log ("You got:\n");
    for (int i{0}; i < numDice; i++)
    {
        SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 14);

        int x{1 + rand() % numFaces};
        std::cout << x << "\n";
        rollTotal += x;
    }
    if (numDice != 1) {std::cout << "\n" << rollTotal << "\n\n";}
    else {Log("\n");}
    return main();
}
```

Comment: You could easily be reading past the end of the string since you unconditionally check values up to input[5]. Also you can get out of the loop with numFaces == 0 then you later run into a divide by 0 here: `int x{1 + rand() % numFaces};`

Comment: Unrelated: [Thou shalt not call `main`.](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start.main#3)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: I don't think the parsing of numbers from a line should be so complicated. Consider taking the line from `getline`, placing it in an `istringstream`, and then sucking the numbers out with `>>`. Once you have numbers a few `if`s will tell you if they're in a valid range or not.

Comment: `std::stoi` is smarter than you give it credit for. `int index;  numDice = std::stoi(input, &index);` will set `index` to the index of the first character that couldn’t be converted. So if that conversion succeeds, check that `input[index] == ‘d’`, then do `numFaces = std::stoi(input.substr(index + 1));`.

Comment: @PeteBecker Ill try this out, thanks. Also, yeah my code is probably bad sorry.

Comment: @PeteBecker I feel really dumb. It works flawlessly now. Thank you, this is much cleaner